# While I am trying to import my own spesific file it gives the error `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named '(file_name)'`

Tags: python-3.x

While I am trying to import my own spesific file it gives the error `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named '(file_name)'`
here is my code:

`import file_name`

i've tried `sys.path.append(r'path\to\my\file')`

but didnt work out as well :(

Comment: Are you inside an IDE? If yes, which one? How are the directories build? Please give a tree like view if the files.

Comment: Can u explain what u mean by INSIDE Ide and _How are the directories build?_

Comment: nvm I found out my questions answer but thanks anyway